# Latex expression in R legend

Tags: r, latex

What should I do to have R correctly show in a legend the equivalent to this latex expression?

```
\alpha \leq \beta
```

The following commands handle \alpha and \beta correctly, but not the \leq symbol:

```
expression(paste(alpha, " leq ", beta))

expression(paste(alpha, " <= ", beta))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use

```
expression(alpha <= beta)
```

For more info check out

```
?plotmath
```